# По нажатию на кнопку класс добавляется, но отображается со второго раза нажатия

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Нужно, чтобы квадратик добавлялся с первого нажатия, а он добавляется только со второго нажатия.

```js
function f1(){
  var sq = document.getElementsByClassName('sq');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  for (i=0; i < sq.length; i++) {
    sq[4].appendChild(div);
    div.classList.add('add');
    console.log(sq[i]);
    
  }
}
```

```css
#line {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 300px;
}
.sq {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
button {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.add {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
</div>
<button id="press" onclick="f1()">Press</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

он и добавляется с первого нажатия, только ты добавляешь его в последний `div`  с классом `sq`, стили у `sq` и `add` одинаковые, следственно визуально первого добаления не видно. 
Согласен с автором предыдущего ответа.
цикл не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Цикл не нужен

```js
function f1() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('add');
  document.querySelector('#line').appendChild(div);

}
```

```css
#line {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 300px;
}

.sq {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

button {
  margin-top: -450px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.add {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
</div>
<button id="press" onclick="f1()">Press</button>
```

---

Второй вариант Для того что бы наглядно показать, что куда вставляется...

```js
function f1() {
  /*Если истинным желанием было вставить DIV и SQ */
  /*а не в LINE, тогда в первом варианте я ошибся */
  var sq = document.getElementsByClassName('sq')[4];
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  /*все и так работает, только как я сказал выше */
  /*Цикл не нужен */
  sq.appendChild(div);
  div.classList.add('add');
}
```

```css
#line {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 300px;
}

.sq {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

button {
  margin-top: -450px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.add {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq"></div>
  <div class="sq" style="padding: 5px;"></div>
</div>
<button id="press" onclick="f1()">Press</button>
```